# How to make the "issuer" the same as domain name in Duende identity server?

Tags: c#, duende-identity-server

There is a Duende identity server (IS) running on a VM, behind an Nginx server. Nginx listens to port 443 and redirects the requests to IS running at 8080. When `https://example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` is visited, the issuer in the configuration is shown as `"issuer":"https://127.0.0.1:8080"` because this is the address Nginx passes the requests to. However, it needs to be `"issuer":"https://example.com"` because this is the configured OIDC Authority in the client.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

You can set it via the `IssuerUri` property on the `IdentityServerOptions` manually if really needed.

https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/options/

As noted there you should not (need) do so. By default the the issuer gets detected dynamically. Starting point for you looking into this might be this class.

https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/main/src/IdentityServer/Services/Default/DefaultServerUrls.cs

IIRC it should respect `X-Forwarded-For` (XFF) and `X-Forwarded-Host` (XFH) headers during this detection. Said that, if your proxy server properly forwards this header to the downstream IS it should just work ™️.

Some documentation around this is available as well.

https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/deployment/proxies/

In the end this is more about ASP.NET in general than Duende IS in particular I'd say.